# Ansible: Copy list of files and run command on any which have changed

Tags: ansible

I have a list of files in an Ansible playbook and I want to perform the following tasks on them:

1. Copy each file from my control machine to the managed node.
2. If and only if the current file has changed, run `mycmd` on the managed node with the filename as an argument (e.g. `mycmd --file myfile`).

I only want to run `mycmd` on files which have changed because it involves some expensive (relative to the other tasks) API calls.

I know how to copy files from a list (`copy` modules + `with_items`), but what I can't work out is how to run `mycmd` with the file that has been copied but only if the file has been changed. `notify` doesn't seem appropriate because the full command run will vary between files.

What's the best way to achieve this result, assuming that it's possible in Ansible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register `copy`'s result and iterate over it:

```
- copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: /tmp/
  with_items:
    - fff1.txt
    - fff2.txt
  register: copy_res

- command: echo {{ item.dest }}
  with_items: "{{ copy_res.results | select('changed') | list }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.item }}"
```

I used `select('changed')` to reduce list only to `changed` items and defined `label` to make output more human readable.

Comment: Fantastic, I wasn't aware of `register` but it solves this particular problem. Thanks!